# ¿Regex que solo haga match despues de que este solo un "$"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando hacer una expresión regular que solo seleccione todo lo que esté después de solo un carácter especial, en este caso `$`. Me explico.

La expresion regular `/\$.*/ig` selecciona lo siguiente:

(El texto en negritas es el seleccionado)

> **$aaaa** 
> **$$asdasd $asdasd** 
> **$$$asdasdasdasd**

Cuando quiero que el resultado sea:

(El texto en negritas es el seleccionado)

> **$aaaa** 
> $$asdasd **$asdasd** 
> $$$asdasdasdasd**$dasda**

Teniendo eso en cuenta eso llegue a la siguiente expresión `/(?<!\$)\$(?!\$).*/ig` que selecciona lo requerido, pero según la misma pagina de [RegExr](https://regexr.com/598fq) y la pagina [Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) la característica lookbehind no es soportada por algunos navegadores. 
Por ende necesito otra expresión que haga lo mismo.

Comment: Prueba con `\$[^\$] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta expresión serviría para el texto de ejemplo de la pregunta:

```
\$[^\$]*$
```

Explicación:

1. `\$` coincide con un carácter `$`. Es necesario usar el carácter de escape (`\`) porque `$` tiene un significado especial en expresiones regulares.
2. `[^\$]*` coincide con cero o más caracteres que **no** sean un `$`.
3. `$` coincide con el final de la cadena.

En regex101: https://regex101.com/r/5H8u2e/2

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesito